# Radiusd keeps getting restarted by launchd

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, launchd, radius

I am reading these errors in the system log file. I have researched [this introduction to radius](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x-server/mac-os-x-server-105-introduction-to-radius/) in order to find a solution as to why Radiusd keeps getting restarted by launchd, but I haven't found a solution.

Has anyone else experienced or solved this issue? btw I am running Mountain Lion on a Macbook Air.

```
 9/5/12 2:38:51.292 PM com.apple.launchd[1]:
 (org.freeradius.radiusd[3055]) Exited with code: 1 9/5/12 2:38:51.292
 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (org.freeradius.radiusd[3055]) Exited with
 code: 1 9/5/12 2:38:51.292 PM com.apple.launchd[1]:
 (org.freeradius.radiusd) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
 9/5/12 2:38:56.686 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (org.isc.named[3056])
 Exited with code: 1 9/5/12 2:38:56.686 PM com.apple.launchd[1]:
 (org.isc.named) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds 9/5/12
 2:39:01.328 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (org.freeradius.radiusd[3057])
 Exited with code: 1 9/5/12 2:39:01.328 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: 

 Process: SleepServicesD [48] Path:
 /System/Library/CoreServices/SleepServicesD Identifier: SleepServicesD
 Version: 1.43 Code Type: X86-64 (Native) Pare
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like FreeRADIUS's `radiusd` and BIND's `named` are crashing, and Mac OS X's centralized lazy-launch daemon `launchd` is configured to keep them alive (restart them if they crash).

Is your complaint that they're crashing, or is your complaint that `launchd` is relaunching them?  If you don't want them running you could use `launchctl(1)` to disable their `launchd` jobs, something like this:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.freeradius.radiusd.plist
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.isc.named.plist
```

If your complaint is that they're crashing, the first thing I'd check is to be sure they were properly compiled and installed for Mountain Lion.  How did you install them?  If you installed them before you upgraded to Mountain Lion, then maybe you need to update them.

For example, if you installed them via MacPorts, you should probably do:

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port upgrade outdated
```

...to upgrade ALL of your MacPorts-installed open source software to the latest versions, which have probably been patched for Mountain Lion compatibility by now.

If you use Homebrew or Fink, there are similar ways to make sure those package managers (and the packages they install) are fully up to date.  I'm just not enough of a Homebrew or Fink user to tell you exactly how to do it.

Comment: I upgraded to Mountain Lion via Mac software install. My package manager is brew but I didn't install those packages w/that. Possible those packages were downloaded as a dependency of some other brew package I installed. So my complaint is do I need them to load and launch successfully in order to have my system run properly (Mountain Lion)? If not I will unload them. I need to read more about launchd. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Nope, you don't need them. RADIUS is a protocol for remotely authenticating users. It's used by enterprise-class Wi-Fi security (802.1X), VPN servers, and PPP servers.

`named` (part of BIND) is a DNS server. If you're not hosting your own domain name on your own DNS service running on your Mac, you probably don't need `named` running.

Comment: Thank you Spiff. You have been a great help. Where can I learn more about this type of stuff?